# Rspec-rails overloading describe, breaking existing minitests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, minitest

I'm using minitest 5.8.4 and rspec-rails 3.5.1. We have a current test suite that's using minitest, but I'm going to slowly migrate us to rspec.

I currently have a lot of tests that are structured like the following:

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  describe "a_method" do
    it "should return the results" do
      assert_a_thing
    end
  end
end
```

As soon as I include `rspec-rails` in my Gemfile, it appears that the `describe` method is then globally overloaded/taken by RSpec, and when I run `rake test` it simply skips all of those tests.

Tests that are are in the structure of `test 'foo' {it 'works' {}}` aren't skipped.

How can I easily make it so that my new RSpec tests, and existing minitests using `describe` co-exist peacefully?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because of [rspec's monkey patching](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/configuration/zero-monkey-patching-mode). In your `spec_helper` disable monkey patching.

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.disable_monkey_patching!
end
```

You would then need to have the following in your specs

```
RSpec.describe "whatever" do
  # any describe, scenario, it blocks here don't need the RSpec. prefix
end
```

Comment: That seemed to help, but now `describe` is unknown to minitest.

Comment: `describe` when I remove rspec is defined in `minitest-5.8.4/lib/minitest/spec.rb:71`. Trying to figure out when I stop the monkey patching (which I actually put at the top of `test/test_helper.rb` for the moment, then describe is entirely undefined. Hmm

Comment: It appears that part of the problem is that minitest rails is attempting to remove describe, and there's calls the superclasses, etc

Comment: I think this actually might be a legit bug. https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/2301 

It seems that disable_monkey_patching just deletes the describe method globally to 'undo' it being defined earlier by rspec.

Comment: Seems to be, but the solution to only require rspec/minitest as you need them makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [j-dexx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38530852/210475), once you've removed the RSpec version of describe you can add back in the minitest ones with another monkey patch. I've done something like that in [this commit](https://github.com/btm/minitest-handler-cookbook/pull/93/commits/065e1d4cb88b02d094edca699a333ae3e54b00ba) for the Chef minitest-handler-cookbook. Mine is base on how `minitest/spec` looks in 4.7.3, but I'm pretty sure it's similar in the newer minitest.

```ruby
RSpec.configure { |c| c.disable_monkey_patching! }

[RSpec::Core::DSL.top_level, Module].each do |klass|
  klass.class_exec do
    # copied from minitest/spec
    # https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/v5.14.4/lib/minitest/spec.rb#L75-L90
    def describe desc, *additional_desc, &block # :doc:
      stack = Minitest::Spec.describe_stack
      name  = [stack.last, desc, *additional_desc].compact.join("::")
      sclas = stack.last || if Class === self && kind_of?(Minitest::Spec::DSL) then
                              self
                            else
                              Minitest::Spec.spec_type desc, *additional_desc
                            end

      cls = sclas.create name, desc

      stack.push cls
      cls.class_eval(&block)
      stack.pop
      cls
    end
  end
end
```